# Rails/Arel User.where(:id => <Some Other Table>.user_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, arel

Hey I'm just getting back into rails and I've forgotten a lot of the stuff needed to work with some associations.

**The Problem:**

I have two tables, `Customer` with fiels `id` and `user_id` and `User` with field `id`. I want to get an array of `Users` such that a `Customer`'s `user_id` is the `id` of a `User`. I know how to do this in SQL but forgot how to do this in Ariel.

**Edit**

So I think I need to explain a little more. I'm taking over an existing project. There's a one-to-one relation between users and customers however only some users have a related customer entity so calling `user.customer` will return `nil` most of the time. I need to edit a page that currently lists all users but now I need to list only users that have a customer record.

The relationships have already been created by the previous developer:

```
class Customer
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => "Refinery::User"
end

Refinery::User.class_eval do
  has_one :customer
end
```

and I have the following code in my controller:

```
def index
  # i need to return an array of users, such that the only
  # users in this array are the ones with a non-nil customer.
  @users = Refinery::User.paginate(:page => params[:page])
end
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define associations in the two classes,  `belongs_to` in customer and `has_many` in user.

You will then be able to use `Users.find(id).customers` etc.

The [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) explains this quite well - look at the example of customer and orders.

**update**
following your question update - try

```
User.where("customer.id IS NOT NULL")
```

or

```
@users = Refinery::User.where("customer.id IS NOT NULL").paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The underlying table for customer is 'cust' (i didn't choose this!) so I tried what you said as well as `.where("cust.id IS NOT NULL")` and got this error: `PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "cust"` Should it matter if the class name for `customer` is `Refinery::Akouo::Customer`?

Comment: Maybe I need to include customers in a join? It looks like this is the SQL output: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "refinery_users"  WHERE (customer.id IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: ok this works but I have to add: `.includes(:customer)` just after `User`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Ariel request for this one.

User :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers
end
```

Customer :

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Code :

```
customer = Customer.find(1)
users = customer.users
```